# Python get index of columns with matching values

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataFrame in which I do not have headers or column names. I want to return the list of indexes in which a certain string ('A' or 'E') exists on the third row - or 2nd row if we're 0-indexing. So a simple 3-row, 3-column example data set is:

```
March          April          May
2019           2019           2019
A              E              F
```

I want to return [0,1] since columns 0 and 1 contain 'A' or 'E'. How can I construct a filter query to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for but I would not use a filter query. I would do this since you already know the index position of the row of interest is 2.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({0: {0: 'March', 1: 2019, 2: 'A'},
 1: {0: 'April', 1: 2019, 2: 'E'},
 2: {0: 'May', 1: 2019, 2: 'F'}})


indices = np.where(df.iloc[2,:].isin(['A', 'E']))
```

This will yield a tuple of `{0, 1}`

Answer (score 2):

I would try this.

```
##get test data
list1 = ['MAY',2019,'A']
list2 = ['MAY',2019,'E']
list3 = ['MAY',2019,'Q']

test_df = pd.DataFrame(zip(list1,list2,list3))

third_row = test_df.iloc[2]
third_row[third_row.str.contains('A|E')].index.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
df[(df=='A') | (df=='E')].dropna(how='all').index
```

This is way more pandas-friendly.

Comment: This doesn't get the index locations that the OP is trying to obtain.

Comment: @ak_slick sorry wrote response from phone initially.